# Show alert below the test field

Tags: html, css

I am working on a form name signin. It contains 1 email field and other 1 is password. These fields are in a div i created in css. What i want is to show the alert below the email field and password field respectively if any of them is left empty.

Comment: show your code please..

Comment: Show what you have tried yet

Comment: Have you checked the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more div below text box

```
<div>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div id="alertName">
</div>
<div>
    <input type="password" />
</div>
<div id="alertPwd">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can use jquery-validate plugin.
Or
If you are using HTML 5, there is attribute required for validation of **empty fields**. LIke below

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

Answer (score -1):

Here's a little working example: You can see the classic asterisk that indicates the field is empty. Also, the javascript functions will run on each change of the input, acting as dynamic functions.

```js
function checkEmptyEmail() {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if (email != '') {
            document.getElementById('emailReq').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('emailReq').style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }

function checkEmptyPasswd() {
        var passwd = document.getElementById('passwd').value;
        if (passwd != '') {
            document.getElementById('passwdReq').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('passwdReq').style.display = 'inline-block';
        }
    }
```

```css
.validation-asterisk-visible {
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: Red;
}
```

```html
Email:       <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  onchange="checkEmptyEmail()" onkeypress="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">
<label id="emailReq" class="validation-asterisk-visible">*</label>
    <p>
Password: <input type="password" id="passwd" name="passwd"  onchange="checkEmptyPasswd()" onkeypress="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">
<label id="passwdReq" class="validation-asterisk-visible">*</label>
```